Semi-Holonomic Constraint Forces Derivation Using d'Alembert's Principle
The other day I was in a lecture of Analytical Mechanics about d'Alembert's Principle, and specifically about semi-holonomic constraint forces.
At the lecture, my professor stated that the constraint force is:
$$Z_{α,i} = λ_i \frac{∂g_α}{∂q̇_i}.\tag{1}$$

$Z_{α,i}$ - the $i$th force of the $α$th constraint
$λ_i$ - the Lagrange Multiplier of the $i$th force
$g_α$ - the $α$th semi-holonomic constraint
$q_i$ - the coordinate

He talked about the idea of the derivation of that and he mentioned that we should use:

the differential form of $g_α$: $$dg_α = A_{αi} dq_i + B_α dt\tag{2}$$
D'Alembert's Principle
virtual displacement $δq_i$

I tried to formalize the proof but I couldn't quite complete it and I feel like I am missing something:
We know that $$Z_{αi} = A_{αi}.\tag{3}$$ So we essentially trying to prove that: $$A_{αi }= \frac{∂g_α}{∂q̇_i}.\tag{4}$$
From here I've tried to substituting $δg_α$ using in one side Taylor expansion, and using the differential form in the other side:
$$A_{αi} = \frac{∂g_α}{∂q_i}.\tag{5}$$
(Assuming that $$δt=δq̇=0\tag{6}$$ because the virtual displacement is fixed and independent on time.)
And although it is super close to the result we want, it is not quite there (it is the derivative with respect to $q$ and not $q̇$).
PLEASE HELP ME :)

please, use mathjax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/

Short of an actual derivation, the main points are:

The semi-holonomic constraints$^1$
$$g_{\alpha}(q,\dot{q},t)~\equiv~\sum_{j=1}^nA_{\alpha j}(q,t)\dot{q}^j+B_{\alpha}(q,t)~\approx ~0, \qquad  \alpha~\in~\{1,\ldots,m\},\tag{A}$$
depends by definition affinely on the generalized velocities $\dot{q}^j$.

The d'Alembert's principle
$$\sum_{i=1}^N ( {\bf F}_i^{(a)} -  \dot{\bf p}_i ) \cdot \delta {\bf r}_i
~+~\sum_{\alpha=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda^{\alpha} A_{\alpha j} \delta q^j~\approx ~0\tag{B}
$$
now contains an extra term of generalized constraint forces for the semi-holonomic constraints (A).



$^1$ OP's eq. (2) seems to be wrong/a misuse of notation. This issue might be the underlying reason for OP's question.
